# I want to hear sound of push notification when sound is turned off (like iOS alarm clock)

Tags: iphone

When I receive a push notification no sound is played when the sound is switched of on the device (with switch on side of iPhone).

When I add an alarm event in the iOS clock I do hear the sound although sound is switched off.

Can I force to play sound with Push notifications when sound is switched off?

---

everybody thanks for the response (this was a programming question)

with regards,
Frank

PS I don't know what is meant by fixing up my accept rate but I'll have a look into that...

Answer (score 4):

You can't, the push notification is handled by the iOS. If the user muted his device there is no way force it to play sound on receiving a push notification.

The reason the alarm can play a sound is because it is not bound by the apple rules for app s from the app store.

Comment: I actually don't believe apps are *forced* to obey the Silent Mode setting - they are just encouraged to do so. Still, this answer is correct: the Alarm Clock ignores Silent Mode, push notifications evidently do not.